# GeoServer 2.20.1 doesn't respect multiple styles with query layers

Tags: geoserver, layers, style, getfeatureinfo, query-layer

I'm having a minor issue with `GetFeatureInfo` and I quite frankly don't know how to solve it.

It's a bit of a long story but here goes:

When I make the following request to our GeoServer it'll return two features - just as expected.

```
SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo
&QUERY_LAYERS=layernameone
&LAYERS=layernameone
&STYLES=style1
&CQL_FILTER=INCLUDE
&FEATURE_COUNT=25
&BUFFER=5
&SRS=EPSG%3A25832
&BBOX=573069.5162775696%2C6224471.533397051%2C573163.7236141923%2C6224565.740733674
&I=113
&J=195
&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson
&WIDTH=256
&HEIGHT=256
&CRS=EPSG%3A25832
```

Using the same layer, but another style, results in zero features - just as expected

```
SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo
&QUERY_LAYERS=layernameone
&LAYERS=layernameone
&STYLES=style2
&CQL_FILTER=INCLUDE
&FEATURE_COUNT=25
&BUFFER=5
&SRS=EPSG%3A25832
&BBOX=573069.5162775696%2C6224471.533397051%2C573163.7236141923%2C6224565.740733674
&I=113
&J=195
&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson
&WIDTH=256
&HEIGHT=256
&CRS=EPSG%3A25832
```

However, when I try to make the following request, it'll return 0 features - but it should return two (the sum of the two previous mentioned requests):

```
SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo
&QUERY_LAYERS=layernameone,layernameone
&LAYERS=layernameone,layernameone
&STYLES=style1,style2
&CQL_FILTER=INCLUDE;INCLUDE
&FEATURE_COUNT=25
&BUFFER=5
&SRS=EPSG%3A25832
&BBOX=573069.5162775696%2C6224471.533397051%2C573163.7236141923%2C6224565.740733674
&I=113
&J=195
&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson
&WIDTH=256
&HEIGHT=256
&CRS=EPSG%3A25832
```

I figured it could be something related to how the request is translated by the GeoServer, so I tried to switch the styles as so:

```
SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo
&QUERY_LAYERS=layernameone,layernameone
&LAYERS=layernameone,layernameone
&STYLES=style2,style1
&CQL_FILTER=INCLUDE;INCLUDE
&FEATURE_COUNT=25
&BUFFER=5
&SRS=EPSG%3A25832
&BBOX=573069.5162775696%2C6224471.533397051%2C573163.7236141923%2C6224565.740733674
&I=113
&J=195
&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson
&WIDTH=256
&HEIGHT=256
&CRS=EPSG%3A25832
```

But this returns 8 features (some of these are the ones returned in the first request - but not all).

Is it even possible to use GetFeatureInfo Request on the same layer with multiple styles?

And if so how would I build the request?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: What do the associated GetMap request map images look like for your four requests?

Comment: The GetMap works as expected and returns the tiles.

Here are the GetMap-response in same order as in the question

First (layernameone, styleone): https://i.imgur.com/90Wlx6r.png
Second (layernameone, styletwo): https://i.imgur.com/3kme0Ol.png
Third: (layernameone with styleone, layernameonewith with styletwo): https://i.imgur.com/Tc82sIV.png
Fourth: (layernameone with styletwo, layernameone with styleone): https://i.imgur.com/0URUO5C.png

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything from the WMS 1.3.0 standard https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=14416 to suggest that syntax `&LAYERS=layernameone,layernameone` is supposed to work. In all the examples the list in `&LAYERS` is a list of distinct layer names.

I believe that you must make two GetFeatureInfo requests and combine the results on the client side.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why using the same layer twice wouldn't work

Comment: Right, with demo layer it indeed works `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=topp%3Astates,topp%3Astates&bbox=-124.73142200000001%2C24.955967%2C-66.969849%2C49.371735&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=,pophatch&format=application/openlayers#toggle` and GetFeatureInfo works as well and prints answers for two separate layers. Can you say if this behavior is defined in the WMS standard and works with all WMS servers?

Comment: `The actual semantics of how a WMS decides what to return more information about, or what exactly to return, are left up to the WMS provider.` ~ OGC® 06-042

Comment: According to 7.4.3.4 it should contains a list of valid names.
It doesn't mention that the names should be unique.

Also it works as expected with GetMap where it easily can distinquish between the styles:

First (layernameone, styleone): https://i.imgur.com/90Wlx6r.png 

Second (layernameone, styletwo): https://i.imgur.com/3kme0Ol.png 

Third: (layernameone with styleone, layernameonewith with styletwo): https://i.imgur.com/Tc82sIV.png 

Fourth: (layernameone with styletwo, layernameone with styleone): https://i.imgur.com/0URUO5C.png

Comment: Maybe related https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/geoserver-users/thread/AF091F71-3D35-44F5-8616-58CCC1E5AA06%40gmail.com/#msg36365136